# Epson drivers in deb

Tags: drivers, scanner

I'm looking for the old Epson scanner drivers. In particular: iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.deb
There is iscan_2.10.0-2_i386.rpm version and sources at official site that can't be build with up-to-date gcc. Alien approach isn't working for the same reason. Old 3rd party site that hosted deb versions is dead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would find a old linux distro that is known to have the correct version of gcc or alien, and install either on an old system, virtual box or run from live cd. Then use the older gcc or alien to get the files needed to install. Then get those files onto the computer you want to install them on, and install from there.

Comment: At the end it all was useless. I'v managed to convert rpm to deb in old kubuntu virtual machine, but these debs can't be installed as some required i386 packages are missing. I was able to unpack them from rpm and copy missing i386 libs manually - that didn't help. Then I've managed to build from sources and even debug the driver at runtime but realized that it needs some proprietary piece of lib that Epson distributes without sources. And it's 32bit So I'm stuck. I'll need whole SANE to be 32bit to make it work. And this will require 32bit vers for GUI frontend I'm using. It doesn't worth it.

Comment: To run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit multi-architecture Ubuntu system, you have to add the i386 architecture and install the three library packages libc6:i386, libncurses5:i386, and libstdc++6:i386:

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  and if that does not work sudo apt-get install multiarch-support after you have done the first ones. Like Kosh!